# TypeScript overload function signature with boolean parameter with dependant return type

Tags: typescript

I would like to call a function with return type based on input boolean parameter, so it returns some type if parameter is false and some other type if parameter is true. I thought overloads are perfect for this case, but TypeScript won't let me use them:

```js
  hello(foo: false): ''
  hello(foo: true): 'bar' {
    if(foo) {
      return 'bar'
    } else {
      return ''
    }
  }
```

Because I get `This overload signature is not compatible with its implementation signature.`

Should I use something else, modify this code or just switch to multiple functions with different names and similar behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attempt to create an overload function is incorrect.
Each variant must be compatible with the underlying implementation

In your code:

- underlying implementation accepts only `true` and returns `bar`
- thus `hello(foo: false): ''` is not compatible with it

```ts
function hello(foo: true): 'bar'
function hello(foo: false): ''
function hello(foo: boolean): '' | 'bar' {
  if(foo) {
    return 'bar'
  } else {
    return ''
  }
}

const aFoo = hello(true);
const anEmptyString = hello(false);
```